# Extra items added to cart on refresh, woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a client site, https://www.ndsclub.com/product/bcaa-page/, where there are **AJAX** 'add to cart' buttons auto-generated by WooCommerce.

If I visit the page with an empty cart and click **ADD** it adds a single item to the cart as expected. The page is reloaded and a popup cart slides into the window.

If I refresh the browser a second item is added to the cart without clicking the **ADD** button.

**How to prevent such bug?**

- This is not a query param problem, there url is clean
- I had a second product on the same page, clicking **ADD** (p1) and then after the reload clicking **ADD** (p2), p1 gets added a second time so I have a total of 3 items in the cart after two clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look on the network tab of the developer tools from your browser, you will see that the product is NOT added by AJAX.

[image: Chrome network tab]

Yes, there is an AJAX-Request but that sends a nonce to "woosb_custom_data" and adds no product to your cart. (blue cross on the screenshot)

Normaly the "add to cart" AJAX-Request should go to an address like "example.com/?wc-ajax=add_to_cart".

The product is add via a normal POST-Request. (red cross on the screenshot)

If you reload the page the browser will send the POST-Request again. 
Try the reload test with an firefox browser and the browser will ask you if you want to send the POST-Request again.

By the way there is an problem with your cart page.

https://www.ndsclub.com/cart/

If you remove all item from the cart (hit the red cross for every item) the cart-view will be white and there is no navigation back to your shop.

Answer (score 0):

**In the case of Simple Product**

Simply add the following script at the bottom of
/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php

**In the case of Variable Product**

Simply add the following script at the bottom of
/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php

```
<script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
    window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
</script>
```

This will prevent the form to execute on page refresh thus keeping your cart as it was before the page refresh. Tried & tested with Woocommerce 7.1.0